# Doom Modeline Configs Does Nothing

Tags: init-file, doom-modeline

The modeline displays correctly but none of the variables changes how it's displayed, no matter where I place them (tested with `doom-modeline-position-column-format` and `doom-modeline-enable-word-count`). This is probably just something very stupid on my end, as I'm very new to emacs and elisp in general so I'm not sure what I'm doing.

This is in my config files, it is loaded in `init.el`:

```el
(use-package doom-modeline
    :ensure t
    :hook (after-init . doom-modeline-mode)
    :init
    (setq doom-modeline-enable-word-count nil)
    (setq doom-modeline-position-column-format '("C%c"))
    (message "doom-modeline-position-column-format is currently set to %s" doom-modeline-position-column-format)
    )
```

I've also tried loading it in `early-init.el`, or putting the `setq` statement in `:config`, before `use-package`, or after. Again the same issue.

A bit more information, I'm not sure if it's needed: I'm running it on a mostly vanilla emacs (emacs-plus on macOS), and I don't have any other theming packages except for doom-themes.